# How to display an equal sign as the only thing in a tablix cell

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How can I display an equal sign as the only thing in a tablix cell?  I have a column that indicates plus, minus for various rows with the last row displaying an equal sign. But, SSRS interprets that as the start of an expression.  I tried various methods to escape the sign but nothing works so far.

Comment: Did you try wrapping it in double-quotations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display the equal sign as text in the tablix cell, you could use this:

```
="="
```

Comment: Shows as an expression in the designer which is confusing, but it correctly displays in the report.  Thanks.